# Does slip.js not working on IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Has anyone used slip.js ( [link to slip.js](https://github.com/pornel/slip) ) in IE9 browser?
It seems like it is not working there?
Here is the [link](https://pornel.net/slip/) to demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try adding the -ms- prefix to the CSS transforms.  See pull request #39 in the github repo (https://github.com/pornel/slip/pull/39/files).

Basically, it detects IE9 browser:

```
var damnYouIe9 = (window.ActiveXObject && window.addEventListener && !window.atob);
```

And then add a prefix to your transform class names

```
var iePrePrefix = (damnYouIe9 ? "-ms-" : "");
var transitionPrefix = "webkitTransition" in testElement.style ? "webkitTransition" : iePrePrefix + "transition";
var transformPrefix = "webkitTransform" in testElement.style ? "webkitTransform" : iePrePrefix + "transform";
var transformProperty = transformPrefix === "webkitTransform" ? "-webkit-transform" : iePrePrefix + "transform";
var userSelectPrefix = "webkitUserSelect" in testElement.style ? "webkitUserSelect" : iePrePrefix + "userSelect";
```